# Internet traffic redirect from WAF to Cloud Network - Encrypted vs unencrypted

Tags: waf

What are security best practices to determine if WAF should redirect Internet traffic to cloud network as encrypted or unencrypted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to encrypt all traffic - especially if it touches any network equipment you do not entirely control.

If the WAF is on a different LAN to the server network why would you not encrypt it? If your servers accept unencrypted traffic it to a large extent makes the WAF redundant - a malicious actor could just send the traffic direct.

There have even been instances of [security agencies accessing traffic within internal communications](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/11/googlers-say-f-you-to-nsa-company-encrypts-internal-network/). Google [now trust absolutely nothing](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/04/06/googles_beyondcorp_security_policy/).